# Создаю собственной детектор. Как находить сразу несколько объектов на изображении?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, tensorflow

Я новичок в машинном обучении, но захотелось попробовать создать собственный детектор. Я знаю, что часто прибегают к трансферному обучению, но хочется попробовать реализовать именно свою модель. Проблема заключается в том, что после обучения (только один класс), модель выдает координаты для одного предполагаемого объекта, но их может быть несколько. Хотя такие модели как yolo, retinanet и т.д, находят сразу несколько объектов на изображении. Может кто-нибудь знает, как такое реализуется?